# how can i find all files that contain embedded crc32's

Tags: command-line, bash, find, regex

how can I find all files that contain embedded crc32's 
e.g. Mydocument190_[F285E17D].pdf using the find command

to clarify the crc32's are always within brackets [F285E17D] and the file names may contain both capital lower-case letters and numbers

further clarification the crc32's are in the file name
and the purpose is to then pipe the results to another command for verification (a lot of files only some of which contain aforementioned crc32's)

Comment: You mean finding all the files which contains `embedded crc32` string?

Comment: should it be part of the file (the pdf) or of the file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd agree with Ahmed on many points (use `find`, use a regex, use `posix-extended`-mode) but for the implementation. There are a few problems:

- `find` has a case-insensitive `-iregex` mode  that makes this better by not needing to specify `A-Z` as well as `a-z`
- Speaking of, CRCs are hexadecimal strings. We only want `[0-F]`… which I think we can specify as a single range. If it doesn't work, use `[0-9a-f]`
- And we need to check for square brackets (or it'll just match any 8-char string).
- `-regex` and `-iregex` search the whole path. We need to make sure your string isn't in a directory name so we exclude any slashes after the CRC.

Here's my current best effort:

```
find -regextype posix-extended -iregex '.*\[[0-f]{8}\][^/]*'
```

This will allow for extensionless files too.

Comment: By the way one could also search *inside* the pdf using pdfgrep and the same regex. That would be sheer beauty. Finding all the files with this pattern and the files that contain the pattern. Not sure that is what the OP is looking for (and hence I did not answer the Q).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the parameter

```
-regex
```

with your find command

you will be then looking for file names with 8 characters in a row that could be a lower case letter, an upper case letter or a number (crc32)

The following command will work fine

```
find . -regex '.*[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z].*'
```

even better you can use the option

```
-regextype posix-extended
```

to chose the number of your pattern repetion {8} as following

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*[0-9a-zA-Z]{8}.*'
```

.* means zero or more random characters

[0-9a-zA-Z]{8} means any character of 0 to 9 or a to z or A to Z existing 8 times in a row

you can also add a file extension or a specific pattern around your crc32 if you want.

You can learn more about **regex** to improve your search pattern